# Displaying rows dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datarow

i want to show all the records which are in ms access database,but it displays only one record...
I have the following code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany.mdb";
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT * From tblCompany";

        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        int cnt = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        textBox1.Text = cnt.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }


    }
```

how can i display all the records from the ms access database,in my DataGridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cnt);
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = row.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = row.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Stecya;- it is giving error that "ArgumentsOutOfRangeException was handled"....:(

Comment: You dataGridView may not have enough rows or cells

Comment: in my datagridview there are two cells and 1 row,BUT in my database there are 4 rows which i want to display in my datagridview....:(

Comment: In order to display all rows dataGridView1 must have that 4 rows. Use `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cnt)`

Comment: where should i setup the "dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cnt) "?

Comment: should i remove the"DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];" from the existing code?

Comment: so what should i do? it is still giving the "ArgumentsOutOfRangeException was handled".:(

Comment: Try `GetValue(0)` and `GetValue(1)`  instead of `GetValue(1)` `GetValue(2)`

Comment: Also you can try to bind your dataTable to dataGridView. This will show all rows and all columns. Just use `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]` after `da.Fill(ds);` and delete that loop

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access rows and columns in the gridview directly, you have to create them

```
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add("c1", "c1");
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add("c2", "c2");
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(10);
```

will add 10 empty rows with 2 columns in the grid, then you can fill them in with values.

Alternativly you can [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) your dataset to the control

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]
```

will display your table with autogenerated columns , without having to setup the gridview.

Comment: i have the rows inmy database i wnt to display that in my datagridview,how?

Comment: In your code , you already have all the rows loaded into your dataset. All you need to do is set the datasource property of the gridview to the table in your dataset. The gridview controll should handle it automaticly, if not check if the AutoGenerateColumns property of the gridview is set to true.